# How to solve $\tan x=x^3$

Tags: trigonometry

I was playing with functions I just learned, like sin, cos and tan, then I saw that the graph of $ y = \tan x$ and $y = x^3$ are pretty similar, that's how I thought of the equation $\tan x = x^3$.
No matter how hard I try, I can't find a way to even start this problem.
(Please consider the fact that I am a highschool student, if it isn't possible to solve this problem with my current knowledge please let me know.)

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form beside the obvious $x = 0$ solution. See WolframAlpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=tan%28x%29+%3D%3D+x%5E3

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: In domain $\mathbb{R}$, it's obvious that there are infinite solutions because $y=\tan{x}$ is a periodic function while $y=x^3$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: The graphs are *not* "pretty similar".

Comment: They seem to be quite the same in $(-\pi /2,\pi /2)$, but if you graph the functions outside that interval, you will see they are not equal. Try graphing $\tan (x) - x^3$ to better see that they are not equal even in $(-\pi /2,\pi /2)$.

Comment: Other than the $x = 0$ solution already mentioned, it's not possible to solve this problem with your current knowledge.  AFAIK, it's not possible to solve it with *anyone's* current knowledge, except to numerically approximate the solutions with a [root-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms).

Answer (score 4):

In order to remove the discontinuities, consider instead that you look for the zeros of function
$$f(x)=\sin(x)-x^3\cos(x)$$ They will be closer and closer to $(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$ because of the cosine.

Using one single iteration of Newton method
$$x_0=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2 \quad \implies \quad x_1=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2 -\frac 8 {\left((2n+1)\pi\right)^3}$$

Just trying

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 4.702832970 &  4.702774539 \\
 2 & 7.851917536 &  7.851915909 \\
 3 & 10.99482207 &  10.99482191 \\
 4 & 14.13681301 &  14.13681299 \\
 5 & 17.27856575 &  17.27856574 \\
 6 & 20.42023481 &  20.42023481 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and we could do much better using a single iteration of Halley or Householder method.

For example, with Halley method, for $n=1$ we would obtain
$$x=\frac{3 \pi  \left(32-576 \pi ^2+729 \pi ^6\right)}{2
   \left(32-432 \pi ^2+729 \pi ^6\right)}=4.702774922$$

**Edit**

Let $k=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$; the first iterate of Householder method is
$$x=k-\frac{3 \left(2 k^6-6 k^2+1\right)}{k \left(6 k^8-36 k^4+5   k^2+18\right)}$$

For $n=1$, the estimate if off by $1.70\times 10^{-9}$.

The next method (no name) gives
$$x=k-\frac{4 k \left(6 k^8-36 k^4+5 k^2+18\right)}{24 k^{12}-216   k^8+28 k^6+360 k^4-60 k^2-19}$$

For $n=1$, the estimate if off by $7.63\times 10^{-12}$.

And we could continue forever, having each time a closed form expression.

Comment: shouldn't there be $\approx$ instead of the last $=$ sign?

Answer (score 0):

You are considering your functions over the real numbers.

You already know from high school that the tangent function ($\tan$) is [periodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) and the cubic power function ($\text{^}^3$) is not periodic.

As already stated in a comment, both functions seem to be quite the same in the interval $(−\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ at first glance.

Let's look at the graphs of your functions over the real numbers (e.g. on Wolfram Alpha):
[$\tan(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+tan%28x%29)
[$x^3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x%5E3)
[$\tan(x)\text{ and }x^3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+tan%28x%29%2Cx%5E3)
[$\tan(x)-x^3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+tan%28x%29-x%5E3)

You already know from high school that $x=0$ is a solution of your equation $\tan(x)=x^3$.

Equations can be solved i. a. by numeric approximations, series approximations or algebraic manipulations.

Let's look if we can solve the equation by algebraic manipulations, or in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

**1.) The two functions cannot be identical over an interval.**

An analytic function is a function that is infinitely differentiable (means arbitrarily often differentiable everywhere in its domain). The domain of $\tan$ and of $\text{^}^3$ is the whole real axis. Both functions are analytic.

Because both functions are analytic, there is, according to the [Identity theorem for analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), no interval where $\tan(x)=x^3$ for all $x$ in this interval.
Therefore there are only single $x$ with $\tan(x)=x^3$.

**2.) No solutions in terms of elementary functions**

$$\tan(x)=x^3$$

With the imaginary unit $i$ and the complex numbers, the function term of every trigonometric function can be represented as rational term of $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$.

So we have:
$$\tan(x)=-i\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}$$
$$-i\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}=x^3$$
$$-i(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})=x^3(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$$
$$-i(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})-x^3(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})=0$$
$$-ie^{ix}+ie^{-ix}-x^3e^{ix}-x^3e^{-ix}=0\ \ \ |\cdot e^{ix}$$
$$-i(e^{ix})^2+i-x^3(e^{ix})^2-x^3=0$$
$$-x^3(e^{ix})^2-i(e^{ix})^2-x^3+i=0$$
$$-x^3e^{2ix}-ie^{2ix}-x^3+i=0$$
$x\to\frac{t}{2i}$:
$$-\frac{1}{8}it^3e^t-ie^t-\frac{1}{8}it^3+i=0$$
$$t^3e^t+8e^t+t^3-8=0$$

We see, this equation is an algebraic equation (means polynomial equation) with rational coefficients, that depends on $t$ and $e^t$. Such kind of equations don't have solutions except $0$ in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

**3.) Solutions in terms of Generalized Lambert W**

$$t^3e^t+8e^t+t^3-8=0$$
$$(t^3+8)e^t+t^3-8=0$$
$$(t^3+8)e^t=-(t^3-8)$$
$$e^t=-\frac{t^3-8}{t^3+8}$$
$$\frac{t^3+8}{t^3-8}e^t=-1$$

We see, this equation cannot be solved in terms of the [Special function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions) [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but in terms of the relatively new Special function Generalized Lambert W:

$$\frac{(t-(-2))(t-(1+i\sqrt{3}))(t-(1-i\sqrt{3}))}{(t-2)(t-(-1+i\sqrt{3}))(t-(-1-i\sqrt{3}))}e^t=-1$$
$$t=W\left(^{-2,1+i\sqrt{3},1-i\sqrt{3}}_{2,-1+i\sqrt{3}),-1-i\sqrt{3}};-1\right)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{2i}W\left(^{-2,1+i\sqrt{3},1-i\sqrt{3}}_{2,-1+i\sqrt{3}),-1-i\sqrt{3}};-1\right)$$

So we have a closed form for $x$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Answer (score 0):

$\def\F{\operatorname F}$

Even though the OP is a high schooler, it would be fun to exactly solve their equation. They likely want the real roots. Let’s apply [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) after taking the multivalued inverse tangent:

$$\tan(x)=x^3\iff x=\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi+\frac i2\ln\left(\frac{2i}{x^3-i}+1\right)\mathop\iff^{} x_k=\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac i2\right)^n \frac{d^{{n-1}}}{dx^{n-1}}\left.\frac{\ln^n\left(\frac{2i}{x^3-i}+1\right)}{n!}\right|_{\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi}$$

for $0,-1\ne k\in\Bbb Z$  defining $x_0=0,x_{-1}=x_1$. Use a [Stirling S1 expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/):

$$\frac{d^{{n-1}}}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{\ln^n\left(\frac{2i}{x^3-i}+1\right)}{n!}=\sum_{m=n}^\infty \frac{S_m^{(n)}(2 i)^m}{m!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(x^3-i)^{-m}$$

Binomial series on $\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} x^{-3m}(1-ix^{-3})^{-m}$ [uses](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28%28-1%29%5Ej+%CE%93%28m%2Bn%2Bj%29%29%2F%28%CE%93%28m%2Bn%29+j%21%29+%28-i%29%5Ej+x%5E%281-n-3%28j%2Bm%2Bn%29%29+factorialpower%28%28-3+%28j%2Bm%2Bn%29%29%2C+-1%2Bn%29%2C%7Bj%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D) [hypergeometric $_3\F_2$](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/)which seemingly has [no special case](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/03/07/). We finally use $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^\infty a_{m,n}=\sum_{1\le n\le m \le \infty}a_{m,n}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^m a_{m,n}$$

to get:

$$\bbox[4px,border: 4px solid navy]{\tan(x)=x^3\implies x_k=\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi-\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{S_m^{(n)}(-1)^ni^{m+n}2^{m-n} \Gamma(3m+n-1)}{\left(\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi\right)^{3m+n-1}\Gamma(3m)m!}\,_3\F_2\left(m+\frac n3-\frac13,m+\frac n3,m+\frac n3+\frac13;m+\frac13,m+\frac23; \frac i{\left(\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi\right)^3}\right);x_{-1}=-x_1,x_0=0}$$

[test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5Bx%2Bsum%5Bsum%5Bsum%5B%28i%2F2%29%5En+%282i%29%5E%28m%2Bn%29+stirlings1%28m%2Bn%2Cn%29%2F%28m%2Bn%29%21+%28%28-1%29%5Ej+%CE%93%28m%2Bn%2Bj%29%29%2F%28%CE%93%28m%2Bn%29+j%21%29+%28-i%29%5Ej+x%5E%281-n-3%28j%2Bm%2Bn%29%29+factorialpower%28%28-3+%28j%2Bm%2Bn%29%29%2C+-1%2Bn%29%2C%7Bj%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C20%7D%5D%2Cx-%3E%282.0%2B1%2F2%29*%CF%80%5D) by changing value of $k$ and compare [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cot%28y%29-y%5E-3%2Cy%3Dlim%5Bx%2Bsum%5Bsum%5Bsum%5Bi%5E%28m+%2B+2n%29+2%5Em+stirlings1%28m%2Bn%2Cn%29+%28-1%29%5Ej+%CE%93%28m%2Bn%2Bj%29%2F%28%CE%93%28m%2Bn%29+j%21+%28m%2Bn%29%21%29+%28-i%29%5Ej+x%5E%281-n-3%28j%2Bm%2Bn%29%29+factorialpower%28-3%28j%2Bm%2Bn%29%2C-1%2Bn%29%2C%7Bj%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C20%7D%5D%2Cx-%3E%282.0%2B1%2F2%29*%CF%80%5D). These links use the hypergeometric function’s series expansion.

Comment: The “generalized Lambert W function” is defined by a (multiple) series expansion. If it has $4$ parameters, then it likely has an expansion in terms of $\sum_n\sum_m\sum_k \,_2F_1$. However the answer above is just a double series of a hypergeometric function and provides all real solutions